# array of 0's coming out as -85993460 instead of 0's

Tags: c++, windows

I have this code to print out the vector `(1 2 3)` from `vector.txt` file but whenever I run the code to turn the vector into a `matrix` the `0`'s that fill up the `matrix` comes out as `-85993460`. Please help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    cout << "Loading vector.txt" << endl;
    FILE *file = fopen("vector.txt", "r");
    int vector[3];
    int b = 0;

    do{
        fscanf(file, "%i", &vector[b]);
        b++;
    }while(feof(file) == 0);


    //clear the screen.
    fclose(file);

    cout << "Loading matrix" << endl;

    int a[3][3],i,j;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(b=0; b<3;b++);
        a[0][i] = vector[i];
    }

    cout << " Vector rotation" << endl;


//Display the original matrix
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
    }
        cout<<endl;
    }
        cout<<"Transpose of above matrix is: "<<endl;
//Display the transpose matrix
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
//get character
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` and naming variable as vector in **VERY** bad idea: `int vector[3];`

Comment: I don't know of any current compiler which would compile this piece of code. `void main` is not C++. The rest is only technically C++ but actually C. Why don't you use `std::string`, `std::vector` and C++ streams?

Comment: Why are you 3* trying to  assign same value in the `a`? in: `for(b=0; b<3;b++); a[0][i] = vector[i];`

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, OP may use VC++; it allows `void main` >o<

Comment: Also, you don't check if the file was opened sucessfully.  EIther place a check to see if `file == NULL`, or use C++ ifstream and check for `!ifstream`.

Comment: Sorry I'm just learning C/C++ right now. Not that familiar with it yet. >.<

Comment: @ikh: You are right, it actually does compile the code, but it emits a warning if you use the `/Za` flag (which unfortunately is not set by default).

Comment: @JeremyGonzales: Your code is pretty much broken beyond hope. You are using techniques which are common in C but are used in C++ only in very rare situations in very advanced software, when normal techniques do not deliver entirely satisfactory results. You should read about `std::string`, `std::vector` and C++ streams; and you will need a good book or tutorial.

Comment: @JeremyGonzales - `Sorry I'm just learning C/C++ right now`  There is no such language as "C/C++".  Either you're learning `C` or you're learning `C++`.  Which one is it?  If your goal is to learn C++, then learn C++.

Comment: Oh alright. Thank you for the advice guys/gals I just really need want to transform a vector into a 3x3 matrix, then transpose it. Can anyone help me at the moment? :(

Comment: @JeremyGonzales: how do you want to "transform" 3x1 into 3x3 ?

Comment: @JeremyGonzales: does your file contain "(1 2 3)" or "1 2 3" ??

Comment: @Piotr S. 3x3 into a 3x1

Comment: @Piotr S.: Yes my vector.txt contains the number 1 2 3

Comment: @JeremyGonzales: with or without `()` ?

Comment: @JeremyGonzales you read in an array of 3 values.  How are you planning to fill a 3x3 matrix with just 3 values?

Comment: @Piotr S: without () just the digits

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : The spaces that need filling will be printed out as 0's

Comment: @JeremyGonzales: Use `={}` to 0-initialize your matrix: `int a[3][3] = {},i,j;`

Comment: Is there a way for me to transpose this without showing the 0's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `={}` to 0-initialize your matrix:

```
int a[3][3] = {},i,j;
```

Comment: May I know why adding {} made transformed the garbage values into 0? I just want to know the reason. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyGonzales: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the matrix. The for loop `for(b=0; b<3;b++);` does nothing, and the line below it only gets executed once. Remove the semi-colon at the end of this for loop if you want to execute the next line, or anything at all, in this loop.

Because the matrix is not initialized in the loop, you are reading garbage values. -85993460 is just whatever was on the stack when the matrix was created.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the outcome did not change in anyway :(

Comment: Regardless, it doesn't look as if you ever initialize the matrix that you are instantiating. Where are you attempting to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a typo, it's more likely that your uninitialized values are showing up as -858993460, which is hex 0xCCCCCCCC, a common value used to fill uninitialized memory when compiling in debug mode.